# Marshaling error in x64

Tags: .net, 64-bit, marshalling

Trying to call DeviceIoControl function from managed code. Have couple structures defined like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct PARTITION_INFORMATION_UNION
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public PARTITION_INFORMATION_MBR Mbr;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public PARTITION_INFORMATION_GPT Gpt;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PARTITION_INFORMATION_MBR
{
    public byte PartitionType;
    public bool BootIndicator;
    public bool RecognizedPartition;
    public UInt32 HiddenSectors;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct PARTITION_INFORMATION_GPT
{
    public Guid PartitionType;
    public Guid PartitionId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
    public UInt64 Attributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 36)]
    public String Name;
}
```

Works fine if I build my application in x86, but fails during run-time if built for x64 with the following error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   PARTITION_INFORMATION_UNION' from assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object
>   field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a
>   non-object field.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**Update**: as far as I understand problem is with last string defined in PARTITION_INFORMATION_GPT. If I replace it with 9 8-byte numbers, or simple comment out and put hardcoded Size into structure attributes - everything works fine.

Comment: This looks like an x64 jitter bug to me, there is no overlap.  You can report it at connect.microsoft.com.  A workaround is `fixed char Name[36]`, unsafe keyword required.

Comment: That's an easiest answer :) But I'm not ready to blame Microsoft for that...

Comment: I just ran into this myself. If you put field offset attributes on the PARTITION_INFORMATION_GPT fields and change it to explicit layout, it works. I found the solution in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786764/creating-multiple-partitions-on-usb-using-c-sharp/35792276

Comment: @J.H. - thank you so much for that reference!!! it just saved me.